# Excel Crashing Completely on Using Intersect

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the 64-bit version of Excel and have an Excel Macro workbook I have created and been using successfully for the last year. Today my workbook started crashing when doing a weekly daily upload that has not previously been an issue (no debug, just crashes and exits completely). I have gone through line-by-line and have found that crash occurs after using the Intersect() method.

This was not a problem when I used the same workbook last week.

I have rewritten a number of these Intersect() instances to use a different functionality to refer back to the same range which has solved the problem I am experiencing today, but I am trying to figure out **why** the Intersect() method is causing a crash in the first place so I can better design future macros.

Comment: It's typically difficult to answer questions about unposted code...

Comment: I found a solution to my current problem, so I was really just looking for someone that knew more about how the Intersect() method uses memory and why it has started leading to complete crashes. The ranges I am trying to refine down with the Intersect() method both function as intended, but something about this method is a problem for me all of a sudden.

Comment: If Excel force closes without message, there is a high probabilty that this is either due to a bug in Excel itself (no one can explain you you what's going on here) or due to a corrupt file (no one can explain …). • Or the code you have written has a memory glitch (no one can explain you if we don't see the code). • Try the same code in a new created file to exlude option 2 from your list of possibilities. • If your code is in a `xlsm` file try to save it as binary format `xlsb`. I already had several issues where huge `xlsm` files got corrupted and `xlsb` seems to be much more stable.

Comment: I often have the same problem with Intersect.
I don't think there's a solution, it's a bug in Excel

Answer (score 0):

I often have a similar problem, I think it's a bug in Excel.

One solution that sometimes does work for me is to ensure that I'm not triggering other events within my subroutine.

ie, put this as the start of the sub:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

and this at the end of the sub:

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```